# how to solve jmeter 3.1 compatibility issue

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, jmeter-plugins

`enter code here`I am using Jmeter 3.1 GUI version. when i run the maven project getting the error
jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from.

I tried so many commination maven dependency it not help to solve the issue. Could you please provide pom.xml for jmeter3.1 jmeter-maven-plugin

My pom.xml

```
     <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <webapp.host></webapp.host>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>regression-l</id>           
        <properties>
            <directory.Name>Regression</directory.Name>
            <filePath>src/test/resources/data/</filePath>                
        </properties>
    </profile>      

</profiles>      
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_jdbc</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.10</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>              
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <jmeterPlugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-extras-libs</artifactId>
                            </plugin>
                        </jmeterPlugins>
                        <propertiesUser>
                            <user.classpath>
                                ${project.base.directory}/jmeter/lib/ext/
                            </user.classpath>
                            <filePath>${filePath}</filePath>
                            <host>${webapp.host}</host>
                        </propertiesUser>
                        <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
                        <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                        <ignoreResultErrors>true</ignoreResultErrors>
                        <testResultsTimestamp>true</testResultsTimestamp>
                        <appendResultsTimestamp>true</appendResultsTimestamp>
                        <resultsFileNameDateFormat>YYYY-MM-dd</resultsFileNameDateFormat>
                        <testFilesIncluded>                             
                            <jMeterTestFile>${directory.Name}/Service.jmx</jMeterTestFile>                                
                        </testFilesIncluded>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>            
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>transform</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformationSets>
                    <transformationSet>
                        <dir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results</dir>
                        <stylesheet>src/test/resources/jmeter.results.detailed.xsl</stylesheet> 
                        <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/detailedresults</outputDir>                           
                        <fileMappers>                                
                            <fileMapper
                                implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.RegExpFileMapper">
                                <pattern>(.*?)\s(.*?)</pattern>
                                <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
                                <replaceAll>true</replaceAll>
                            </fileMapper>
                            <fileMapper
                                implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                                <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
                            </fileMapper>
                        </fileMappers>
                    </transformationSet>
                </transformationSets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>            
    </plugins>                           
</build>
```

Comment: Are you using jmeter plugins in your test plan?

Comment: yes i am using jmeter plugins, i guess that is one of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the minimal working pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.blazemeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvn-jmeter</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>maven-jmeter-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you are using extra libraries or [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) - you will need to modify it to add missing dependencies, for "vanilla" JMeter test it should work fine given you place it the following way (folder structure):

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── test
        └── jmeter
            └── Your_Test.jmx
```

In case if you still experience problems we'll need full stacktrace as the partial error you've posted doesn't tell the full story therefore it is impossible to indicate the root cause.

References:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin#jmeter-maven-plugin)
- [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath)